# Certain keys not working without other key input

Tags: laptop, keyboard

A week ago, I began having intermittent issues with keys not sending input under certain, strange conditions.

The specific keys are 6, 7, 8, y, u, h, j, and n.

The problem isn't with the hardware, because:

a) They work fine if I hold Shift and send upper case input just as normal.
b) They also work fine if I start holding one, and then press shift, at which point I get normal lower-case input.
c) Sometimes, pressing one of these keys and then pressing another key in rapid succession sends that sequence of inputs but in reverse (i.e. typing "net" returns "ent" instead).

Has anyone experienced something like this before? I'm at the end of my wit.

My operating system is Win 10 1903 and my machine is an ASUS ROG GL503GE.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc The issue does occur in safe mode, yes.

Comment: Try to rollback to a System Restore point from before this happened (hopefully you haven't installed new software during this period).

Comment: This isn't an option, since I haven't created a restore point recently enough, but the good news is that I've come closer to fixing the problem at the source. Normally, the issue simply doesn't crop up, and it's always after I unplug my laptop from its charger, mouse, and my earbuds, and then close it for transport. Doing one of these things fixes it; I just need to find out how to reproduce it.

Comment: What if you change the order: First close laptop, then unplug devices?

Answer (score 0):

I took the laptop, turned it upside down, shook it, and now the keyboard works perfectly. I'll probably get some canned air and use it on the keyboard later.